# Browser-sync not refreshing when I save (Chrome and sublime text 2)

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext2, browser-sync

When I save changes to my css code, Browser-sync doesn't refresh the browser automatically. I still have to click on my browser window and hit F5 to see the changes I have made. I installed npm and browser-sync and it shows I am connected to browser-sync. I am using Sublime Text 2 and Chrome (Dev 56.0.2924.87) on a windows 7 operating system.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [browser-sync does not refresh page after changes with Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163754/browser-sync-does-not-refresh-page-after-changes-with-gulp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to fix or update deprecated npm packages. [How to determine path to deep outdated/deprecated packages (NPM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329944/how-to-determine-path-to-deep-outdated-deprecated-packages-npm/36335866#36335866)

What also helped - Gulp. I used Gulp in combination with browser sync and now my browser automatically refreshes when I save changes.
 I used the following link to guide me through using Gulp for the first time: https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/